# Django - Why am I getting an OperationalError (only) when I am using the shell?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have encountered a strange situation. What's wrong?

When I run `python manage.py shell` from the project directory, import a model (any model), and try to access its `Model.objects` (`objects.all()`, `objects.create()`, ...), it throws an `OperationalError` as quoted below.

```
>>> from Interface.models import ClientUser
>>> ClientUser.objects.all()
```

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Interface_clientuser

```
>>> ClientUser.objects.create()
```

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Interface_clientuser

I have tried deleting the database and then running `python manage.py migrate`, closing everything and restarting my computer, and staring really hard at the code (lol), but to no avail..

Interestingly, my unit tests all pass; including, for instance, ones that call `ClientUser.objects.create()`

Here is the ClientUser model, though I don't think the model is the problem (error occurs for all models and unittests pass..)

```
class ClientUser(models.Model):
    guid = models.UUIDField(null=True, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)

    def most_recent_device(self):
        return self.devices.order_by('-pk').first()

    # I just put this classmethod in. I'm not sure if this will work, and went to the shell to try it, and that's when I noticed this issue. I've tried commenting it out and it makes no difference.    
    @classmethod
    def get_by_guid(cls, guid):
        return cls.objects.get(guid=guid)
```

Here is the complete stacktrace from the shell (above):

```
>>> from Interface.models import ClientUser
>>> ClientUser.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Interface_clientuser

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 248, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1068, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Interface_clientuser
```

Answer (score 1):

You tables is not created...

Run `makemigrations` to check if exist any migrations to be applied

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

And then run `migrate` to apply all your migrations in your database

```
python manage.py migrate
```

**EDIT** How many databases you use? this error is throwed by sqlite too, are you using sqlite in your settings and your tests?

Comment: That was my first thought too. Unfortunately, I have already tried running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. Even deleting the database and running the migrate command (see details in question)

Comment: 1 database, sqllite. It's also important to note that the unit tests work

Comment: Ye, im starting to think your teste case maybe is ignoring the error or maybe using other database

Comment: Nah, it's not... I found the answer though

Comment: Double check if your ´manage.py´ file is calling the right ´settings´, if you using multiple settings files maybe your manage is calling one diferente setting with maybe production database or something like that

Comment: It's too late to try that because I've fixed the issue.. but good to know that I can pick between settings files! Thanks! `python3 manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.prod_settings`

Comment: Ye you can do that running runserver, or changing it at your manage.py (and at your wsgi you using WSGI server), usually i use environment variables to define which environment is that... dev, qa, prod and call my settings based on it

Comment: Even though I answered my own question, Upvote for getting in there with suggestions of things to help debug. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is additional magic required beyond:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Run this arcane beast:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

And rejoice!:

```
C:\Code\Py\django\HealthCheck>python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: Interface, messages, rest_framework, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table Interface_clientuser
    Creating table Interface_clientgroup
    Creating table Interface_device
    Creating table Interface_supportrequest
    Creating table Interface_fcmmessage
    Creating table Interface_healthcheckalert
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

C:\Code\Py\django\HealthCheck>python manage.py shell
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from Interface.models import ClientUser
>>> ClientUser.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

Comment: What the version of your Django? --run-syncdb im pretty sure is for old versions (1.7 or less if im not wrong)

Comment: @DiegoVinícius 2.0.7

Comment: @DiegoVinícius I'm not sure why this was suddenly necessary.. `app_name = "Interface"` in `Interface.urls.py`, but it has always been.. crazy...